# Changing mapped image to another mapped image

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap

I have a mapped image, where I have five areas (five objects which are interesting for me). After clicking these five areas I want to change an image and therefore change map. It's like a game where you should find things.

My problem is that, when I change image I have an error, I use **mapper.js**.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null**

My code: (HTML)

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <img id="MainImage" class="mapper"
         src="0100.png" border="0" width="1000" height="707" orgWidth="1000" orgHeight="707" usemap="#map1" />

</div>

<map name="map1" id="map1">

    <area id="0101" shape="poly" onclick='myFunc(id)'
          coords="615,559,637,546,658,542,658,585,677,667,661,669,641,675,618,619" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
    <area id="0102" shape="poly" onclick='myFunc(id)'
          coords="903,537,919,534,928,554,948,659,935,662,922,626,915,659,902,657" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

    ....

    <area id="0105" shape="poly" onclick='myFunc(id)'
          coords="243,364,259,364,262,385,269,405,275,441,245,443" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
</map>


<map name="map2" id="map2">

    <area id="0201" shape="poly"
          coords="26,292,34,283,47,298,38,312,23,313" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

    ......

    <area id="0210" shape="poly"
          coords="685,505,696,472,716,498,713,572,688,566" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
</map>
```

And here goes JavaScript:

```
var clickedIDs = [];
    var currLength = 5;

    function myFunc(id) {
        if (clickedIDs.indexOf(id) != -1) {
            return;
        }
        clickedIDs.push(id);
        document.getElementById(id).className = "noborder icolor00ff00";
        if (clickedIDs.length == currLength) {
            var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            myDiv.innerHTML = '<img id=\'MainImage\' class=\'mapper\' src=\'0200.png\' border=0 width=1000 height=707 orgWidth=1000 orgHeight=707 usemap=\'#map2\' />';
        }
    }
```

When I click first five objects and change image using InnerHTML I have error.

Comment: Which file has that error? Which line? Normally, an error gives a good starting place to look.

Comment: mapper.js - This file is unstructured i.e the code is written in two lines so I cannot really tell the line. You can see this javascript right here http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/